# When should we use the versions tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, when someone asks a question and he is saying `I am using Ubuntu 11.04`. Should the question also be tagged `11.04` or not ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I see any mention of version (either software version which I lookup on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ or Ubuntu version) I tag it accordingly.

It could be used for determining the age and relevancy of the question. Tags can be used for searching: https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/11.04+upgrade

I find the version tag more useful to questions related to upgrades, bugs, drivers and the use of new software like Unity. Software recommendations and shell-scripting questions are examples of questions where the Ubuntu version does not matter.

Comment: I agree. It might turn out not to be relevant to the issue but it does help people in the future who are looking for version-specific things.

Comment: So , for specific questions like applications,scripting, coding, the version tags are not necessary. But for major things that concern the version itself ;i.e installation,updating,upgrading,drivers a person should use these tags. am I right ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Keep in mind that this does not imply that you should omit the version tags for all applications, applications may still retain a different behavior across versions. Another thing to add: bugs are especially version-dependent.

Answer (score 13):

I would *definitely* avoid adding a version tag just for the sake of having it.

Version tags can be dangerous if the community starts to believe that every question, no matter what, has to have a version tag.

Only version tag posts that provide at least some evidence they are in fact tied to a specific version of Ubuntu.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I've managed to ask such a question. Because I see some questions that maybe it doesn't need to have a version tag to it. Also we should note that there are so many things change every version as Jorge Castro mentioned above.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to what Lekensteyn I use the following ideas myself:

- If something changed a ton, like say unity, I tag those with the versions so that it's obvious which major release people are using, but I don't tag general stuff like apt, dpkg, or something like that.
- Kernel/Hardware/Video stuff for sure since hardware detection is version specific there.